# Recuperar información de un usuario de Firebase Authentication

Tags: firebase, react-native

estoy usando Firebase y necesito recoger la información de los usuarios de la base de datos, para el sistema de login utilizo el servido de Firebase Authentication y claro los usuario no se guardan en Firestone, actualmente puedo obtener la información del usuario con el que estoy logeado de la siguiente manera.

```
var user = firebase.auth().currentUser;
```

Pero yo lo que necesito es obtener la informacion del usuario que quiera pasandole por ejemplo el UID del usuario que necesito su información.

Muchas gracias.